# How to Bind Model Class in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am retrieving records from store procedure, but it does not bind data into view.

Here is ModelContext class:

```
namespace MyTesting.Models
{
    public class TvSerialDB
    {
        public static string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TvSerialContext"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        public IEnumerable<TVSerialByGroup> tvserialgroupby(string serialname)
        {
            List<TVSerialByGroup> tvserials = new List<TVSerialByGroup>();
            using (con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("pSerialListGroupBySerialName", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SerialName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = serialname;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    TVSerialByGroup tvs = new TVSerialByGroup();
                    tvs.Series_Name = sdr["Series_Name"].ToString();
                    tvs.Image_Url_Big = sdr["Image_Url_Big"].ToString();
                    tvs.Season_No = sdr["Season_No"].ToString();
                    tvs.TotalEpisode = sdr["TotalEpisode"].ToString();
                }
            }
            return tvserials;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is ModelClass:

```
namespace MyTesting.Models
{  

    public class TVSerialByGroup
    {       
        public string Series_Name { get; set; }
        public string Season_No { get; set; }
        public string Image_Url_Big { get; set; }
        public string TotalEpisode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is controller class:

```
public ActionResult ListAllSeason(string serial)
        {
            try
            {
                TvSerialDB tvcon = new TvSerialDB();
                List<TVSerialByGroup> tv = tvcon.tvserialgroupby(serial).ToList();                  
                return View(tv);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

When i run this application it does not display any record nor it gives error.
When i debug this code through breakpoint it returns rows into store procedure but in views it does not bind data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not adding your model instances to the collection.

```
while (sdr.Read())
{
    TVSerialByGroup tvs = new TVSerialByGroup();
    tvs.Series_Name = sdr["Series_Name"].ToString();
    tvs.Image_Url_Big = sdr["Image_Url_Big"].ToString();
    tvs.Season_No = sdr["Season_No"].ToString();
    tvs.TotalEpisode = sdr["TotalEpisode"].ToString();
    tvserials.Add(tvs); // add this
}
```

Side note: Since your initializing `List<TVSerialByGroup>`, you can make your method `public List<TVSerialByGroup> tvserialgroupby(string serialname)` and then you do not need `.ToList();` in the `ActionResult` method.